# getting mysql syntax error while using parameters in mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, macos

Getting sql syntax error in nodejs

Am using this code :

```
async function getNotificationFsql(data) {
    var query = "select * from notifications where id>${data.start} and receiver=${data.recId} limit 10";
    var record = await db.sequelize.query(query ,
        function (err,results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while getting data from MYSQL     :-   ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Notifications data which we got from MYSQL     :-   ' + results);
            }
        }
    );
    // console.log(record);
    console.log('Notifications      :-   ' + record[0]);
    return record[0];
};
```

And I got:

> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
> errno: 1064,
> sqlState: '42000',

> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{data.start} and receiver=${data.recId} limit 10' at line 1",

> sql: 'select * from notifications where id>${data.start} and receiver=${data.recId} limit 10',
> parameters: undefined
> },
> sql: 'select * from notifications where id>${data.start} and receiver=${data.recId} limit 10',
> parameters: undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not replaced the placeholders with definite values.

Comment: Don’t build queries with string substitution, use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, am doing this wrong

i solve this error doing this :

```
var query = "select * from notifications where id>"+data.start+" and receiver="+data.recId+" limit 10";
```

Comment: This code is free for SQL injection...